# How to invite Facebook friends to my iOS application in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift4, facebook-invite-friends

I am developping an iOS application using Swift 4.

I need that the user can invite his Facebook friends to use this application.

I tried this code :

```
 func inviteFacebookFriends(){

    let dialog = FBSDKAppInviteDialog()
    let content:FBSDKAppInviteContent = FBSDKAppInviteContent()
    content.appLinkURL = URL(string: "https://example/fbid")
    content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = URL(string: "http://www.queness.com/resources/images/png/apple_ex.png")
    dialog.content = content
    dialog.delegate = self
    do {
        try dialog.validate()
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }

    dialog.show()
}
```

But nothing happened, there's no dialog appears.

please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I’ve answered to your question. Did you see it ?

Comment: thank you for your help.I should find another solution.

Comment: Yes you should. Can you please accept my answer as it answers your question ?

Answer (score 0):

**Facebook invite is no longer allowed by Facebook SDK**. There's no way to use `FBSDKAppInviteDialog` anymore.

> With the release of the Facebook SDK version 4.28.0, App Invites is deprecated. It will be supported until February 5, 2018.

[From Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/archive/docs/app-invites/?locale=en_US)

You will have to find an other way than Facebook to invite friends.